# Swift and comparing C typedef enums

Tags: xcode, swift

I recently updated to Xcode-Beta4. I'm working with a c api and there is a typedef enum like this:

```
typedef enum {
    XML_ELEMENT_NODE=       1,
    XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE=     2,
    ...
} xmlElementType;
```

Now I have a xml node, which type I want to check. Therefore the right way would be:

```
if currentNode.memory.type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE {
```

In Beta 3 I had to replace `XML_ELEMENT_NODE` with `1`. Now this does not work anmyore. In both cases I get the error `xmlElementType is not convertible to UInt8`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest workaround is to find the header and replace the `typedef enum` with an `typedef NS_ENUM(...)`. The problem with this solution is that everybody in your team has to make the changes.

The problem is caused by the fact that the C enum is converted into an opaque type (struct?) `C.xmlElementType`. This type has one single property `value` of type `UInt32`. Unfortunately, this property is not public. You can call it from the debugger but using it in compiled code results in an error.

I managed to do a workaround using `reflect` but it's a big hack:

```
extension xmlElementType : Equatable {
}

public func ==(lhs: xmlElementType, rhs: xmlElementType) -> Bool {
    var intValue1 = reflect(lhs)[0].1.value as UInt32
    var intValue2 = reflect(rhs)[0].1.value as UInt32

    return (intValue1 == intValue2)
}

var elementType = currentNode.memory.type

if elementType == xmlElementType(1) {
    println("Test")
}
```

I think this is a bug. Either the equality should be defined or some way to cast the struct to an integer.

**EDIT:**

Another option is to add an `inline` conversion function to your bridging header:

```
static inline UInt32 xmlElementTypeToInt(xmlElementType type) {
    return (UInt32) type;
}
```

And then define equality as

```
public func ==(lhs: xmlElementType, rhs: xmlElementType) -> Bool {
    return ((xmlElementTypeToInt(lhs) == xmlElementTypeToInt(rhs))
}
```

However, the most simple option I have found is to brutally cast the struct to an `UInt32`:

```
public func ==(lhs: xmlElementType, rhs: xmlElementType) -> Bool {
    var leftValue: UInt32 = reinterpretCast(lhs)
    var rightValue: UInt32 = reinterpretCast(rhs)

   return (leftValue == rightValue)
}
```

Note this is less reliable because you have to make sure that the struct actually has 32 bytes and it is not an `UInt8`, for example. The C conversion function is more stable.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I have to call this equation very often and this way exploded the time, my application now needs for parsing the xml file (from 2 seconds up to 45 ;))

Comment: @Lupurus Added more options.

Comment: The last way works better and faster, but it's not beautiful and it's as well slower as in Xcode beta 3 :( Hmmm... Your second way doesn't work "... not convertible to UInt32"

Comment: @Lupurus - really? Where did you put it? A C enum should be convertible to an integer.

Comment: Unfortunately, `typedef NS_ENUM(...)` didn't work for me (**XCode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)**). The `inline` conversion with a Swift equality worked like a charm, though! The inline conversion goes to the bridging header, that's true. What I found convenient for the equality is to have `MyLib-Bridging-Helpers.swift` right in the same folder with the bridging header and put the equality there, because this is where it logically belongs. Very nice solution, thank you!