# Using an Objective C enum in Swift back in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have an enum defined in Objective C and used as a datatype in a Swift object.

Now I'm using that swift object in Objective C and I'd like to access the property.

However the property isn't added to the "xxxx-Swift.h" file in the class.  I know it's possible to use Swift enums in Obj C with @objc prepending it but I don't have much control over this enum since it's auto generated from existing Objective C code.

Comment: if it's an Objective-C enum just make sure it's `typedef`ed as as an [`NS_ENUM`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25078514/332733)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift and comparing C typedef enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872475/swift-and-comparing-c-typedef-enums)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your use case is, but here is a quick example of how an enum defined in Objective-C can be used in a Swift class, which can in turn be used in Objective-C.

Here is the Objective-C header (`oclib.h`):

```
#ifndef oclib_h
#define oclib_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {A, B, C} oc_enum_t;

void useSwiftClassInC();

#endif /* oclib_h */
```

Here is the corresponding Objective-C `.m` file (`oclib.m`):

```
#import "oclib.h"
#import "swift_c_1-Swift.h" // Need this to have access to Swift types; the swift_c_1 part will be your product module name.

void useSwiftClassInC() {
    UseEnum *ue = [[UseEnum alloc] initWithE:B i:444];
    printf("In Objective-C useSwiftClassInC(): m_Enum = %d, m_Int = %d\n", ue.m_Enum, ue.m_Int);
    ue.m_Enum = A;
    ue.m_Int = 10;
    [UseEnum printUseEnum: ue];
}
```

And here is the Swift file:

```
// Swift class that uses an enum from Objective-C    
class UseEnum : NSObject // NSObject inheritance is important!
    {
        var m_Enum : oc_enum_t
        var m_Int : Int32

        init(e : oc_enum_t, i : Int32)
        {
            m_Enum = e
            m_Int = i
        }

        static func printUseEnum( x : UseEnum )
        {
            print("In Swift UseEnum::printUserEnum: m_Enum = \(x.m_Enum), m_Int = \(x.m_Int)")
        }
    }

    // This calls an Objective-C function that does the following:
    // - creates a UseEnum object
    // - prints it out from Objective-C
    // - modifies it
    // - calls printUseEnum(), implemented in Swift, to print the object
    useSwiftClassInC()
```

The bridging header just has

```
#import "oclib.h"
```

You have probably seen this documentation already, but if not, here it is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Please provide more details about your specific situation if this doesn't answer your question.  Here is the output I get from the example:

```
In Objective-C useSwiftClassInC(): m_Enum = 1, m_Int = 444
In Swift UseEnum::printUserEnum: m_Enum = oc_enum_t(rawValue: 0), m_Int = 10
```

An interesting situation arises if a data type defined in Swift is used in the signature of an Objective-C function that needs to be called from Swift.  Xcode won't let us import the `*-Swift.h` into an Objective-C header or into a bridging header.  A solution is to use `@class` forward declaration of the Swift type.  Thus, if in the above example we needed an Objective-C function that takes `UseEnum` as a parameter, we could have something like this in `oclib.h`:

```
...
@class UseEnum; // Forward declaration must come before UseEnum is used!
...
void useSwiftClassInC_1(UseEnum * useEnum);
...
```

Comment: Oh interesting, you made a wrapper class.  Here's my use case:  So there's an Objective C library with some enum.  Call it ObjCLib.  That objective C library is used in a Swift library.  Call it SwiftLib.  The Swift library has a settings class with one property being the enum type.  I have a project written in Objective C that uses SwiftLib.  I want to set the value of an enum property in the settings class in SwiftLib but the property doesn't get added to SwiftLib-Swift.h like all the other properties do since the data type isn't back compatible with Objective C.

Comment: Expanded the answer to include forward declarations, they are also described in the referenced Apple docs.  Now you should be well equipped.  All the best to you.