# Swift print() printing name of the type instead of the enum associated value

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, webrtc

I'm printing a couple of enums in delegate methods for WebRTC. Comparing them or using switch statements works fine, but one of the enums just prints its type name instead of associated value:

```
func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCPeerConnectionState) {
    // I don't know why this only prints the type name and not the associated value
    print ("peerConnectionState \(newState)")
}

func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCIceConnectionState) {
    print("ICEConnectionState: \(newState)")
}
```

This prints

```
peerConnectionState: RTCPeerConnectionState
ICEConnectionState: connected
```

The RTCPeerConnectionState never prints its associated value, even though if I check its rawValue, it's a valid member of the enum. Both of them are defined in PeerConnectionState.h as below:

```
/** Represents the ice connection state of the peer connection. */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RTCIceConnectionState) {
  RTCIceConnectionStateNew,
  RTCIceConnectionStateChecking,
  RTCIceConnectionStateConnected,
  RTCIceConnectionStateCompleted,
  RTCIceConnectionStateFailed,
  RTCIceConnectionStateDisconnected,
  RTCIceConnectionStateClosed,
  RTCIceConnectionStateCount,
};

/** Represents the combined ice+dtls connection state of the peer connection. */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RTCPeerConnectionState) {
  RTCPeerConnectionStateNew,
  RTCPeerConnectionStateConnecting,
  RTCPeerConnectionStateConnected,
  RTCPeerConnectionStateDisconnected,
  RTCPeerConnectionStateFailed,
  RTCPeerConnectionStateClosed,
};
```

I don't know a whole lot about ObjC-Swift bridging, it all seems to "just work". What's the difference between the two enums that only seem to affect print()?

Comment: I don't think the ObjC code keeps this meta data. I think you have to manually extend these enums with conformance to `CustomStringDescribable` add a computed property `description`, which uses a switch on the enum value to return the correct (hard coded string) case name.

Comment: Apparently, if you define your enums in Objective C with NS_ENUM and name them just right, LLVM makes them available in Swift 'for free' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872475/swift-and-comparing-c-typedef-enums. Both enums above are working in this manner, Xcode even auto generates switch blocks with all the enum values, the problem seems confined to print()

Comment: Whoops - you were right Alexander, there was a file in the sample code I'd started with that has exactly what you describe, and it was missing the class in question. I was mistaking Swift bridging the enum labels for description strings.